# How to alter deeply nested children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In the following code, I'd like all `<p>` tags having a "data-mini-slug" attribute to be returned as `<input>` tags instead.

The following code works when returning one `<p>` dom element.

How would you convert all nested `<p data-mini-slug="hello">` elements as inputs, while keeping the dom structure? Does React have a built-in solution for this?

```js
function hoc(WrappedComponent) {
    return class Enhancer extends WrappedComponent {
        render() {
            const elementsTree = super.render();
            let newProps = {};
            if (elementsTree) {
                const miniSlug = elementsTree.props['data-mini-slug']
                if (elementsTree.type === "p" && miniSlug) {
                    newProps = { value: `New props is ${miniSlug}` }
                    const props = Object.assign({}, elementsTree.props, newProps)
                    return <input {...props} />
                }

            }
            return elementsTree
        }
    }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // return <p data-mini-slug="deepChild" data-new-value="Deep nested child" />
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hoc dom element conversion</h1>
                <p data-mini-slug="child" data-new-value="Surface child" />
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p data-mini-slug="deepChild" data-new-value="Deep nested child" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default hoc(Example)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a loop by having the function to call itself in the cloned element.

```
import React from 'react'

function iterateOverChildren(children) {
    return React.Children.map(children, child => {
        if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
            return child;
        }

        if (child.props.children) {
            child = React.cloneElement(child, {
                children: iterateOverChildren(child.props.children)
            });
        }

        return alterChild(child);
    });

}

function alterChild(child) {

    let newProps = {};
    const miniSlug = child.props['data-mini-slug']
    if (child.type === "p" && miniSlug) {
        newProps = { value: `New props is ${miniSlug}` }
        const props = Object.assign({}, child.props, newProps)
        child =  <input {...props} />
    }

    return child
}

function hoc(WrappedComponent) {
    return class Enhancer extends WrappedComponent {
        render() {
            const elementsTree = super.render();
            return iterateOverChildren(elementsTree.props.children)
        }
    }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // return <p data-mini-slug="deepChild" data-new-value="Deep nested child" />
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hoc dom element conversion</h1>
                <p data-mini-slug="child" data-new-value="Surface child" />
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p data-mini-slug="deepChild" data-new-value="Deep nested child" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default hoc(Example)
```

Answer (score 0):

The React solution would be create a component that would render `p` or `input` depending on some prop something like

```
function Comp(props){
   if(props.dataMiniSlug)
     return <p/>
   else
     return <input/>
}
```

If for some reason you **have to** modify the DOM (virtual) the way you trying to do, you could recursively traverse children with [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) API like this.

```
render() {
  const rootNode = super.render();
  return transform (rootNode)
}

transform(node) {
  if(node.props.children){
     return React.Children.map(element.props.children, transform)
  }      
  if (node.type === "p" && node.props['data-mini-slug'] !== undefined) {
      return <input { ...node.props, value: `New props is ${node.props['data-mini-slug']}`}/>
  }
  return node
}
```

Again i would strongly advise you to reconsider this whole approach otherwise hope it is helpful somehow.

Comment: Thanks but that's actually where I'm stuck. How to recursively traverse in an effective way over the deeply nested children while keeping the dom structure? When altering the elementsTree with `elementsTree.props.children[i] = newComponent` I get an error saying it's read-only

Comment: Edited my answer. What about the first approach? Is there reason you can't go with it?